# Program stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get this program to run properly. it should do as the pseudo code do as described although when I execute the program and try to open a new account if I put more than one character in the customer name field the program just goes into an infinite loop and I have clue how to fix this issue.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int choice, account_number;
long acc_entry;
long acc_no = 112280;
double balance, deposit, withdrawal;
int interest = 1.67;
string customer_name;

void display_menu();
void get_choice();
void menu_selection(int selection);
void open_account();
void make_withdrawal();
void make_deposit();
void add_interest();
void display_transaction();

void main()
{
    get_choice();

}

void display_menu()
{
    system("CLS");
    cout << "\n\n\t\t\t\tACCOUNT MENU";
    cout << "\n\t\t\t\t============\n";
    cout << "\n\t\t\t\t1. Open Account";
    cout << "\n\t\t\t\t2. Make Withdrawal";
    cout << "\n\t\t\t\t3. Make Deposit";
    cout << "\n\t\t\t\t4. Add Interest";
    cout << "\n\n\t\t\t\t5. Exit";
}

void open_account()
{
    system("CLS");
    cout << "\n\n\t\t\t\tOPEN ACCOUNT";
    cout << "\n\t\t\t\t============\n\n";
    cout << "\tPlease enter your name\n\n\t";
    cin >> customer_name;
    cout << "\n\n\tPlease enter initial despoit\n\n\t";
    cin >> deposit;
    balance = balance + deposit;
    account_number = acc_no + 1;
    cout << "\n\n\tYour new account number\n\n\t" << setfill('0') << setw(8) << account_number;
    get_choice();
}

void make_withdrawal()
{
    system("CLS");
    cout << "\n\n\t\t\t\tMAKE WITHDRAWAL";
    cout << "\n\t\t\t\t===============\n\n";
    cout << "\tPlease enter Account Number\n\n\t";
    cin >> acc_entry;
    if (acc_entry == account_number)
    {
        cout << "\n\n\tPlease enter amount to withdraw\n\n\t";
        cin >> withdrawal;
        if (withdrawal > balance)
        {
            cout << "\n\n\tYou are exceeding your limit";
            cin.ignore();
            cin.get();
        }
        else
        {
            balance = balance - withdrawal;
            cout << "\n\n\tYour new balance\n\n\t" << fixed << setprecision(2) << (char)156 << balance;
            cin.ignore();
            cin.get();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\n\n\tAccount number does not exist.";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.get();
    }
    get_choice();
}

void make_deposit()
{
    system("CLS");
    cout << "\n\n\t\t\t\tMAKE DEPOSIT";
    cout << "\n\t\t\t\t============\n\n";
    cout << "\tPlease enter Account Number\n\n\t";
    cin >> acc_entry;
    if (acc_entry == account_number)
    {
        cout << "\n\n\tPlease enter amount to deposit\n\n\t";
        cin >> deposit;
        balance = balance + deposit;
        cout << "\n\n\tYour new balance\n\n\t" << fixed << setprecision(2) << (char)156 << balance;
        cin.ignore();
        cin.get();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\n\n\tAccount number does not exist.";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.get();
    }
    get_choice();
}

void add_interest()
{
    string yn;
    system("CLS");
    cout << "\n\n\t\t\t\tADD INTEREST";
    cout << "\n\t\t\t\t============\n\n";
    cout << "\tPlease enter Account Number\n\n\t";
    cin >> acc_entry;
    if (acc_entry == account_number)
    {
        cout << "\n\n\tDo you wish to add interest [Y/N]\n\n\t";
        getline(cin, yn);
        if (yn == "Y" || yn == "y")
        {
            balance = balance * interest;
            cout << "\n\n\tYour new balance\n\n\t" << fixed << setprecision(2) << (char)156 << balance;
            cin.ignore();
            cin.get();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\n\n\tAccount number does not exist.";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.get();
    }
    get_choice();
}

void display_transaction()
{
    system("CLS");

    cout << "\n\n\t\t\t\tCLOSED";
    cout << "\n\t\t\t\t======\n\n";
    if (account_number != 112280)
    {
        cout << "\tCustomer Name  : - " << customer_name;
        cout << "\n\n\tAccount Number : - " << setfill('0') << setw(8) << account_number;
        cout << "\n\n\tBalance        : - " << fixed << setprecision(2) << (char)156 << balance << "\n\n";
    }
    cin.get();
}

void get_choice()
{
    display_menu();
    do
    {

        cout << "\n\n\t\t\t\tEnter Number [1-5] : ";
        cin >> choice;
        menu_selection(choice);
    } while 
        (choice << 1 || choice >> 5);
        cin.ignore();

}

void menu_selection(int a)
{
    switch (a)
    {
    case 1:
    {
        open_account();
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        make_deposit();
        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        make_withdrawal();
        break;
    }
    case 4:
    {
        add_interest();
        break;
    }
    case 5:
    {
        display_transaction();
        break;
    }
    default:
        {
        cout << "hello";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather a lot of code to trawl through. Please be considerate and submit an sscce. By the way, `int interest = 1.67;` is not doing what you want. See for yourself with the debugger.

Comment: the main issue in my code just now is only in the open account function

Comment: I'll give you a big hint. `<<` and `>>` aren't comparison operators. (See `get_choice` function).

Answer (score 2):

```
void get_choice()
{
    display_menu();
    do
    {

        cout << "\n\n\t\t\t\tEnter Number [1-5] : ";
        cin >> choice;
        menu_selection(choice);
    } while 
        (choice < 1 || choice > 5); // << and >> aren't for comparison
        cin.ignore();

}
```

Comment: daft mistake i know, been staring at this code for about 3 hours know everything is just starting to look the same sorry.

Answer (score 2):

In your `get_choice` function, you have a `do-while` loop with the following condition:

```
while (choice << 1 || choice >> 5); // this is going to run for a bit
```

`<<` and `>>` are not comparison operators; rather, they are [bit shift operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_shift_operators).

Because your choice can be shifted either left or right, it goes into an infinite loop. It's a simple fix, really - change them to comparison operators!

As for the customer name, if there are spaces or newlines, `std::cin` will stop reading at the first one. Be sure to use `std::getline` for reading strings from stdin.

In `open_account`, replace this:

```
cin >> customer_name;
```

with this:

```
std::getline(cin, customer_name);
```

Also, fix this line:

```
int interest = 1.67; // This should be a double
```

You shouldn't be using globals really, but that's a whole different story.

Comment: Or the entire `std` namespace. We can go on, but I think that's better-suited for codereview than here. :)

Comment: Yeh I know I shouldn't be using global variables, this code was just given to us from a lecturer to debug and write up test logs on, i've changed the operators. still going into an infinite loop if  string customer_name; has a space in it.

Comment: @RobertAndrewClarkson Ah, sorry about that. Edited.